# Is it possible to push multiple grouped values into multiple discrete arrays using oneliner in perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a perl regex from which I have to push `$1` and `$2` and `3` into three separate arrays.

Currently I am pushing `$1` into the arrays in 3 separate statements like this:

```
foreach (@time){
    push @hour, $1 while $_ =~ /(\d\d):\d\d:\d\d/g;
    push @minute, $1 while $_ =~ /\d\d:(\d\d):\d\d/g;
    push @second, $1 while $_ =~ /\d\d:\d\d:(\d\d)/g;
}
```

I know that scalar variables can be assigned like this:

```
my ($i, $j, $k) = $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/;
```

Doing the arrays the same way stores all the groups into the first array.

```
my (@i, @j, @k) = $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/g;
print "@i \n";
print "------- \n";
print "@j \n";
print "------- \n";
print "@k \n";
print "------- \n";
```

Returns:

```
12 23 43 15 33 54 00 12 23    
-------

-------

-------
```

Is there a way to push groups into separate arrays in a one liner the same way scalar variables can do?

Edit:

```
$time = "12:23:54
15:33:54
00:12:23";
```

Comment: `while /.../` makes no sense without `/g`.

Comment: @choroba I added the value of time. This is not the actual variable I am using. I am actually using regex in an XML file which I know is generally not good, however it is a simple regex. I used `/g` in my original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match more than once.

```
my $time = "12:23:54\n15:33:54\n00:12:23";
my (@hour, @minute, @second);
while ($time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/g) {
    push @hour,   $1;
    push @minute, $2;
    push @second, $3;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend something like

```
1 while $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)(?{ push @hour,   $1;
                                          push @minute, $2;
                                          push @second, $3
                                        })/g;
```

as it's much less readable.

The following might be more readable, but I'd still go with the first solution.

```
my @matches = $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/g;
($hour[@hour], $minute[@minute], $second[@second])
    = splice @matches, 0, 3 while @matches;
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do it in a one liner like for scalars?

Comment: You can't push to 3 arrays at a time.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept your answer in 3 to 4 days, just waiting to see if someone else has some other answer